# Magento 2: Include PHP script in header

Tags: magento2

When adding in my custom scrpts (JS and CSS), I add in `<css src="css/custom-styles.css" after="-"/>` or `<link src="js/custom-js.js" />` in the `default_haed_blocks.xml` file. I have a PHP script which will generate some dynamic meta information, but how would I include it in every page like the CSS and JS files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can in layout default.xml write this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="head.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="block_name" template="path_to_file.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

and put content from your script to .phtml template.

Hope this helps